# Rails scope / class method to select items where association is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

Can't seem to wrap my head around this problem. I have a message model below

```
Message
 # content:string
 # original_id:integer
 # sender_id:integer
 # receiver_id:integer

 has_one :reply, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "original_id"
 belongs_to :original, class_name: "Message"
```

Each message can only have one reply and the reply message will have its corresponding original message.

What I'd like to do is create a scope or a class method that allows me to pull replied messages in one batch and unreplied messages in another.

Something like

```
 # return messages that have a reply present
 def self.replied
   where(reply.present?)
 end

 # return messages that have no reply
 def self.unreplied
   where(reply.nil?)
 end
```

so I can chain the methods and ultimately pull messages with

```
 user1.messages.replied
```

It doesn't currently work because I can't use the where clause unless it's a DB column...so I was thinking about adding a "replied" boolean column into the DB so I could use the where clause but there's probably a solution to this that I'm just not thinking about. A scope with a lambda? I'm stuck right now.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find those that have been replied is fairly straightforward:

```
scope :replied, joins(:reply)
```

as anything without a reply will be filtered out with an INNER JOIN.  To find those without replies is a bit more complex - you can either use a LEFT JOIN or an EXISTS subquery to accomplish this.  `includes` is a simple way to force a LEFT JOIN:

```
scope :unreplied, includes(:reply).
                  where(replies_messages: {id: nil}).
                  where(original_id: nil)
```

An EXISTS subquery may be somewhat more efficient, but more complex to write (at this time), as it would involve invoking Arel tables (or Squeel).  For most cases a LEFT JOIN would be 'good enough', and `includes` is a quick-and-dirty way to force the API to use one.

Comment: Thanks PinnyM! Could you help me modify the where clause on the :unreplied so that I exclude reply messages from that scope? If there are two messages A and B where B is replying to A. :replied scope returns A and :unreplied should return nil (currently it returns B)

Comment: Thanks PinnyM! I tried to chain the "where(original_id: nil)" to your original "LEFT JOIN messages replies ON messages.reference_id = replies.id" statement and it didn't have the same effect (didn't filter out the reply messages). Not sure what the difference is between that and "includes"

Comment: @JeffLocke: After writing the complete query using the "LEFT JOIN" syntax - add `.to_sql` to see what query is actually being sent to the database.  Compare that SQL with what is generated using `includes`.  Post back if it's not clear to you.

Comment: Remember that this is for `has_one :reply`. Make sure to use `uniq` if the association is `has_many`: `scope :replied, -> { joins(:replies).uniq }`